# How to parse values from existing dataframe to new column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have the following dataframe  on which i am trying to add a new column taking values from existing dataframe from each row, can anyone please guide what needs to be done to take value from existing dataframe and insert it in new column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Ticker": ['MSUSDSP5', 'MSUSSPVP', 'MSCBICC0'],
  "Levels": [50, 40, 45],
  "Pkey": [71763307, 5456454, 5454587],
  "Date": ['16Jun2022', '16Jun2022', '16Jun2022'],

}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 

df['sql_query'] = 'call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE(%s, %s, %s, NULL, NULL)' %  (df['Pkey'], df['Date'], df['Level']
print(df)
```

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: What's the point of storing the SQL query when you can just generate it when you need it?

Comment: Hi Nick, because at the end all the sql query will get transferred to aws snapper and from there the prices will get inserted in database

Comment: why this question has been closed ?

Comment: You want to extract the data from within the brackets to columns?

Comment: yes gtomer, i need to add a new column (sql-query) and parse values on it from existing columns (Pkey, levels, date) in each row

Comment: `df['sql_query'] = df.apply(lambda r:"call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE(%s, '%s', %s, NULL, NULL)" %  (r['Pkey'], r['Date'], r['Levels']), axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks Nick, you made my day, i appreciate your time and effort

Comment: what's the role of r here ?

Comment: @RahulVaidya no worries. `r` is just a variable which represents the current row (because `axis=1`) of the dataframe.